# JSONArray and encoded image on Android tablet

Tags: java, android, exception, arrays

I have a problem with my first Android App. I want to ask a PHP server for a name and image, using an cardid. This works well, but JSONArray throws an exception when I try to split up the long string I get. This is the method I use on the Android device:

```
public static Object[] getIdCardOwner(String card)
{
    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cardid",card));
    Object returnValue[] = new Object[2];

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
       }
   //convert response to string
   try{
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"), 16);
          sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

          String line="0";
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                         sb.append(line + "\n");
           }
           is.close();
           result=sb.toString();
           }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
           }
   //paring data

   try{
         jArray = new JSONArray(result);
         JSONObject json_data=null;
         for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                returnValue[0] = json_data.getString("name");
                returnValue[1] = json_data.getString("image");
            }
         }
         catch(JSONException e1){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e1.toString());
         } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
   return returnValue;
}
```

This is the String result I get before the exception happens:

```
{"0":"4016612622","card":"4016612622","1":"Peter Poulsen","name":"Peter Poulsen","2":"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","image":"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"}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
05-14 14:13:00.723: E/log_tag(359): Error converting result org.json.JSONException: Value {"image":"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","2":"\/9j\/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP\/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAAAeAAD\/4QMpaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLwA8P3hwYWNrZXQgYmVnaW49Iu+7vyIgaWQ9Ilc1TTBNcENlaGlIenJlU3pOVGN6a2M5ZCI\/PiA8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm
```

Can anyone tell me, what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance
Peter

Comment: Perhaps, "image" is not a String. It looks like a picture. It may be that some kind of character is giving poblemas.

Comment: Yeah it is an base64 encoded picture, but since I'm getting both the name and the image, I need some way to take them apart, before decoding the image... Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data they're supplying for json_data.getString("image") is not a string.
It's an image.

Check the JSON manually. It it's outputting image data then you need to get them to change the JSON. E.g. it should look like this:

```
    "src": "Images/theImage.png",
```

Comment: Hmmm feeling like a big noob, but when it is an encoded jpg, isn't it a String until you decode it again?
And ones again thanks for helping me. :-)

Comment: yeah - but encoding the image in JSON is making things complex and error prone. if you can avoid it then do so.

Comment: The Image is in an mysql database on the php server, since I was told it is the fastes and best way to transfer it to and Android App, if I only want to use it temporary. Is there some better way to do it or do you have a trick up your sleve you can show me?

Comment: I took you advice, dumped the whole code and started again, using another approach and this worked in first try. :-D
Thanks for taking your time answering my noob question. :-)